# Power Query: Change the datatype of elements in a nested list?

Tags: types, powerquery, nested-lists

I'm trying to do a interpolation for which I found a code example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69959544/19328275.
It is written for integers, but I need decimals. I was able to change the code until the creation of the column "dayList", which contains lists. If I write
`#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "dayList", each {[BusinessDays]..[shifted BusDays]-0.1})`
instead of
`#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "dayList", each {[BusinessDays]..[shifted BusDays]-1})` (subtracting 0.1 instead of 1), I get an Expression.Error: Number is out of range of a 32 bit integer value.
How can I change the datatype of the list elements within this step?

Comment: Please provide a sample input and desired output

Comment: You will need to produce your **List** differently if you are not using integers. If the intervals are regular, you could use the `List.Numbers` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specs for using `expression..expression` as a list-generator specifically mention **whole numbers**. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-values#list:

> To include **a sequence of whole number in a list**, the a..b form can be used
> { 1, 5..9, 11 }     // { 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 }

However, you can use [`[List.Numbers]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-numbers) instead.